# Python: Having trouble with a code for class

Tags: python

**Prompt:**
Many user-created passwords are simple and easy to guess. Write a program that takes a simple password and makes it stronger by replacing characters using the key below, and by appending "q*s" to the end of the input string.

```
i becomes !
a becomes @
m becomes M
B becomes 8
o becomes .
```

Ex:

```
If the input is:
mypassword

the output is:
Myp@ssw.rdq*s
```

**What I have so far:**

```
#assign variables

word = input()

password = ''

#checking for and modifying user's password if containing the characters: i, a, m, B, or o
for character in word:

    if(character=='i'): #if user's password contains the letter i change to !
        word += '!'
    
    elif(character=='a'): #if user's password contains the letter a change to @
        word += '@'
        
    elif(character=='m'): #if the user's password contains the letter m change to M
        word += 'M'
        
    elif(character=='B'): #if the user's password contains the letter B change to 8
        word += '8'
        
    elif(character=='o'): #if the user's password contains the letter o change to .
        word += '.'
        
password = (word + 'qs')

#output final password

print(password)
```

My output is messed up. I input the password as mypassword and the output is mypasswordM@.qs

Can someone please help me by telling me where I'm messing up?

Comment: You need to append the characters to a new variable, not the same variable you're processing. Or just use the `str.replace()` method.

Comment: Can you use dictionaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.replace()`

```
word = 'mypassword'

word = word.replace('i','!')
word = word.replace('a','@')
word = word.replace('m','M')
word = word.replace('B','8')
word = word.replace('o','.')

word = word + 'q*s'

print(word)

>>> Myp@ssw.rdq*s
```

You can also put all the `.replace()` on one line,

```
word = word.replace('i','!').replace('a','@').replace('m','M').replace('B','8').replace('o','.')
```

Comment: You need to assign the result back to the variable.

Comment: Thank you! This helped immensely .

Answer (score 0):

Following your original logic, you need to initialise a word to return, otherwise all characters get appended to your old password.

```
word = input()

password = ''

#checking for and modifying user's password if containing the characters: i, a, m, B, or o

for character in word: # update password rather than word

    if(character=='i'): #if user's password contains the letter i change to !
        password += '!'
    
    elif(character=='a'): #if user's password contains the letter a change to @
        password += '@'
        
    elif(character=='m'): #if the user's password contains the letter m change to M
        password += 'M'
        
    elif(character=='B'): #if the user's password contains the letter B change to 8
        password += '8'
        
    elif(character=='o'): #if the user's password contains the letter o change to .
        password += '.'
        
    else: # add else statement for when symbols do not get replaced 
        password += character

print(password)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word = input()
password = ''

# Modify characters i, a, m, B, and o in password
for character in word:
    if character == 'i':     # IF character equals 'i' change to '!'
        password += '!'
    elif character == 'a':   # ELSE IF character equals 'a' change to '@'
        password += '@'
    elif character == 'm':   # ELSE IF character equals 'm' change to 'M'
        password += 'M'
    elif character == 'B':   # ELSE IF character equals 'B' change to '8'
        password += '8'
    elif character == 'o':   # ELSE IF character equals 'o' change to '.'
        password += '.'
    else:                    # When symbols do not get replaced 
        password += character

print(password + 'q*s')      # Make password stronger by adding "q*s" to the end of 
                             # the input string
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question in my studies, and it was designed to test your knowledge in loops. While there are simpler ways of coding this, I feel this may be more along the lines of what the exercise is looking for.

```
word = input()
password = ''

for character in word:                 #Begin looping through string
    if character == 'i':               #If 'i' is present, replace with '!'
        word = word.replace('i', '!')
    elif character == 'a':             #Else If 'a' is present, replace with '@'
        word = word.replace('a', '@')
    elif character == 'm':             #Else If 'm' is present, replace with 'M'
        word = word.replace('m', 'M')
    elif character == 'B':             #Else If 'B' is present, replace with '8'
        word = word.replace('B', '8')
    elif character == 'o':             #Else If 'o' is present, replace with '.'
        word = word.replace('o', '.')
else:                                  #Changes have been made, append 'q*s'
    word += 'q*s'
    password = word                    #Set new password

print(password)
```